# Is this the right way to iterate through an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Here is the code in question:

```
var L1 = [];
var Q1 = [];

function populateListOne() {
  var limit = prompt("please enter a number you would like to fill L1 to.");

  for (i = 2; i <= limit; i++) {
    L1[i] = i;
  }

  for (n = 2; n <= L1.length; n++) {
    var count = 2;

    if (n == count) {
      var index = L1.indexOf(n);
      L1.splice(index, 1);

      Q1[n] = n;
      count = count + 1;
    }

    for (j = 0; j <= L1.length; j++) {
      if (L1[j] % 2 == 0) {
        var secondIndex = L1.indexOf(j);
        L1.splice(secondIndex, 1);
      }
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "iteration " + "1" + ": " + L1 + " Q1 = " + Q1;
}
```

I’m currently working on a homework assignment where I have to setup a queue. All is explained in my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RyterINC/bye57okk/33/).

#### Problem description

Essentially, the part I’m stuck on is iterating through each instance of the array and then taking the value out if the modulus is identical to 0. However, as you can see when I run the program, it doesn’t work out that way. I know the problem is in the second for loop I just don’t see what I’m doing wrong.

The way I read it is, if `j` is less than the length of the array, increment. Then, if the value of the index of `L1[j]` modulus 2 is identical to 0, set the value of `secondIndex` to whatever the index of `j` is. Then `splice` it out. So, theoretically, only numbers divisible by two should be removed.

#### Input

A single number `limit`, which will be used to fill array `L1`.

`L1` will be initialized with values 2, 3, ... `limit`.

#### Process

Get the starting element of array `L1` and place it in array `Q1`.

Using that element, remove all values in array `L1` that are divisible by that number.

Repeat until array `L1` is empty.

Comment: Thank you for editing. My first post so I don't quite have the hang of the format.

Comment: I'm sorry - I may be missing what you are trying to accomplish here - are you trying to generate an array/sequence of odd numbers up to a given input?

Comment: essentially, the assignment is, user filles Q1 array to a certain value. Starting with 2, Iterate through the array and for every value divisible by 2 remove it. then add 2 to L1 array. Then do with with 3, so on so forth, until Q1 is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have issues with looping over an array if you're changing the array within the loop. To help with this, I tend to iterate from back to front (also note: iterate from `array.length - 1` as the `length` element does not exist, arrays are key'd from 0):

```
for(j = L1.length - 1; j >=0 ; j--)
```

For your first loop, you miss the elements `L1[0]` and `L1[1]`, so I would change the first loop to:

```
L1 = [];
for(i = 2; i <= limit; i++)
{
  L1.push(i);           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Array indices and putting entries

You initial code used an array that was initialized to start at index 2. To avoid confusion, of what index to start at, **start with index 0** and iterate until `array.length` instead of a predefined value `limit` to ensure that you go through each element.

The following still works but will be more of a headache because you need remember where to start and when you will end.

```
for (i = 2; i <= limit; i++) {
    L1[i] = i; // 'i' will begin at two!
}
```

Here's a better way:

```
for (i = 2; i <= limit; i++) {
    // 'i' starts at 2 and since L1 is an empty array,
    // pushing elements into it will start index at 0!
    L1.push(i); 
}
```

#### Use pop and slice when getting values

When you need to take a peek at what value is at the start of your array, you can do so by using `L1[0]` if you followed my advice above regarding array keys.

However, when you are sure about needing to remove the starting element of the array, use `Array.slice(idx, amt)`. `idx` specifies which index to start at, and `amt` specifies how many elements to remove beginning at that index (inclusive).

```
// Go to 1st element in L1. Remove (1 element at index 0) from L1.
var current = L1.splice(0, 1);
```

#### Use the appropriate loops

To make your life easier, use the appropriate loops when necessary. For loops are used when you know exactly how many times you will iterate. Use while loops when you are expecting an event.

In your case, 'repeat until L1 is empty' directly translates to:

```
do {
    // divisibility checking
} while (L1.length > 0);
```

## JSFiddle

Here's a complete [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kvjbq35p/) with in-line comments that does exactly what you said.

Comment: `L1.push(i)` is probably better than `L1[i - 2] = i`

Comment: I agree. That works too. :) I advice OP to review array functions (pop, push, slice, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

In this section:

```
    for(j = 0; j <= L1.length; j++){
    if(L1[j] % 2 == 0)
    {
       var secondIndex = L1.indexOf(j);
        L1.splice(secondIndex, 1);

    }
    }
```

you should splice with j instead of secondIndex.

Change L1.splice(secondIndex, 1); to L1.splice(j, 1);

Comment: Thank you! This makes perfect sense. I was already indexing a variable that was acting as the index. I got the exact output I wanted.